# IIS8.0 Response size limit?

Tags: iis-8, static-files

I am trying to serve up some hefty (really hefty) static web pages.  The one I am playing with is 20Mb, and contains image links to about 5000 images.

I'm seeing some errors, where after a certain point no more images are loaded- I get a failed GET response from the server.  In my file, it starts with all images linked after line 26064 until the end of the page.

Is there some response limit in IIS?  I checked out the Response Cache size, but no effect by changing the max to 0, which the docs state is unlimited cache.

Any ideas?

Comment: See: http://www.ckode.dk/server-configuration/tuning-iis-7-for-static-content and: http://serverfault.com/questions/448942/why-is-iis-7-5-flushing-file-cache-very-often

Comment: Is this an ASP.Net web site?

Comment: Nope not an ASP.Net site... just static pages.